# Joomla 3.3.3 - device-specific module display and hiding

Tags: templates, joomla, module, position

I am building a site using the JA Purity III template where on PCs etc a module displays on the right hand side next to the article. However, on small screens the module is pushed underneath the article. What I'd really like to do is hide the module on the smallest of screens and display a modified copy of the module in a position above the article.

With this template I can turn on and off the display of modules for various sizes of responsive device, but turning them off for Pcs etc also turns them off them off for all devices.

An example: http://www.timhillpsychotherapy.com/test2014/introversion.html on a PC has the green module next the article, on a mobile screen it gets pushed below. Instead, on a small scree only I'd like to have an variant of the green module above.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 2 modules in your template and show / hide them due to css media queries.

That would be good to add a module suffix to help you select them: `Advanced -> Module Class Suffix`.

Your css selector has to be like:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  div.module_modsuffix1 { display: none; }
  div.module_modsuffix2 { display: block; }
}

@media (min-width: 701px) {
  div.module_modsuffix1 { display: block; }
  div.module_modsuffix2 { display: none; }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you emmanuel for your answer. I am a beginner with CSS but I will try your solution and see if I can do it without further help. If it works, I will mark the question as complete; if not, I might ask you a further question in a couple of days.

Comment: Nice, please tell me how will it go.